# How to check why the cdrom cannot be open exclusively

Tags: linux, hardware, burning, data-cd

Sometimes when I try to burn an ISO image, the message that "/dev/sr0" cannot be open exclusively appears. `lsof` does not shows any program that opens "/dev/sr0" (I checked for aliases too).

Comment: What is the exact error message? Please copy-paste (in an English locale, i.e. `LC_MESSAGES=C burning_command /dev/sr0`).

Comment: (I use en_GB locale anyway). I'll post it as soon as I reproduce it.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: Did you ever figure out what this error was about?

Comment: @Caleb: No, I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
fuser -a /media/cdrom
```

Usually that tells you which process is accessing or locking the resource.

Comment: cdrom is not mounted. It is blank CD.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using a bad fork of the CD writing software.  It seems that Debian forked the cdrecord tools five years ago, and one fork does not work well, including emitting errors about exclusive locks on the CD device.

Get a copy of the real software by going to http://cdrecord.berlios.de/

Also (even though you may not be using ubuntu) the following may be informative: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cdrkit/+bug/149076

Comment: Even if cdrkit is unrelated to your problem, I would replace it with the proper official cdrtools.  cdrkit is buggy and very outdated, all its programs included.  I want an updated mkisofs, even on my cdromless netbook.  There is a really good ppa located https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/cdrtools

I actually was able to use those packages in Debian, with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Also, lsof can be a great help in determining who's using a filesystem.

> sudo lsof | grep /media/cdrom

Comment: The second sentence of the question says he already tried `lsof`

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear, he said he tried checking lsof against the device name of the cdrom, I was suggesting checking lsof against a mount point where the cdrom might be mounted, however, I did fail to realize it was a blank CD.

Comment: In previous question I commented also that cdrom is not mounted...